# In Eclipse maven build success ,but compilation error is there when the functionality is accessed with URL

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, java-8

> Code explained:
> Default error is: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Duplicate local variable i

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< com.myapp.myappproduct:MyApp >--------------------
[INFO] Building MyApp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ MyApp ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.9.0:compile (default-compile) @ MyApp ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ MyApp ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\MyFolder\MyCodeStuff\Changes\Implementations\MyAppProject\MyApp\spring-mvc-example\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.9.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ MyApp ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ MyApp ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:3.0.0:war (default-war) @ MyApp ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [MyApp] in [C:\MyFolder\MyCodeStuff\Changes\Implementations\MyAppProject\MyApp\spring-mvc-example\target\MyApp]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\MyFolder\MyCodeStuff\Changes\Implementations\MyAppProject\MyApp\spring-mvc-example\WebContent]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [751 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\MyFolder\MyCodeStuff\Changes\Implementations\MyAppProject\MyApp\spring-mvc-example\target\MyApp.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ MyApp ---
[INFO] Installing C:\MyFolder\MyCodeStuff\Changes\Implementations\MyAppProject\MyApp\spring-mvc-example\target\MyApp.war to C:\Users\ganapathym\.m2\repository\com\myapp\myappproduct\MyApp\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\MyApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing C:\MyFolder\MyCodeStuff\Changes\Implementations\MyAppProject\MyApp\spring-mvc-example\pom.xml to C:\Users\ganapathym\.m2\repository\com\myapp\myappproduct\MyApp\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\MyApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.672 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-01-19T12:34:33+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You have the error message `Duplicate local variable i` so have you checked all your servlets and JSP pages if they contain a duplicate variable named `i`?

Comment: Yes , in same java class , duplicate variable is there and its showing error symbol , but maven build is success

Comment: Then maven does not build this file (possible error in your maven pom.xml). Fix the error and try again.